# How to build a string that have a fixed length, and append data to it at specific starting positions?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to build a string that have a fixed length of pixels, and append three variables to it at specific starting positions in pixels, variables data constantly changes but their starting positions are constant within the string.

// Below is what am trying to accomplish if I were to use Graphics DrawString

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(656, 5); 

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) 
{ 
  Font font = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point); 
  g.Clear(Color.White); 

  g.DrawString(first_number, font, Brushes.Black, 10, 1; 
  g.DrawString(full_name, font, Brushes.Black, 150, 1); 

  g.DrawString(second_number, font, Brushes.Black, 550, 1);
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about a RichTextBox, or a multi-line TextBox...?

Comment: You can't position in to a `TextBox`, but you could overlay three labels.

Comment: Please, paste the code you have already tried. Thank you

Comment: You *could* measure a white space char and insert the number of spaces needed to *cover the distance*. It won't be that much precise, though, using the standard space (char 32). You could use another white space type. It depends on whether a user needs to modify or otherwise *interact* with the text. Editing it, for example. But this is valid for the X coordinate. The Y one, another story.

Comment: Unless, with `X` and `Y`, you mean Char and Line numbers.

Comment: You cannot do this, as you have no control over the size of the font the user is using. Users can override UI settings like font size using their browser (or OS), which means that even if you were to use hardcoded coordinates assuming font size 12; you would never be able to guarantee that this is the font size that is actually being used. On top of that, users with a small resolution may even be experiencing word wrapping which is also going to impact the coordinates you should be using. I suggest revisiting your intended approach as it's going to end up with a lot of edge cases.

Comment: Another option is to use the RichTextBox indentation support (`SelectionIndent`) or Tab Stops (`SelectionTabs`), all measures in Pixels. This also applies to the X coordinate, not the Y. Unless it 's ok with you to make the Y coordinate relative to the Font size and the Line height. So, you can't choose *any* Y position, only in certain *ranges* of values. But, this all depends on what the text is for. If a User can select it. Otherwise, you can just Paint it wherever you want, using a Custom Control derived from TextBoxBase.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The question as posted clearly can't be solved; but maybe you didn't tell us all? You can easily draw the strings to any place in a, say, Panel.. Do you actually need editing features?? Or you could fill the tbox with spaces in a fixed size font and replace some..

Comment: TaW you are right, I need to be able to compose a string of one line. This line have 6 digits number at the beginning and a fullname roughly 10 spaces after that number, and another 6 digits number at the end of the string. All of this will be done programmatically without the user interaction, and then the entire string of a fixed length will be passed to an API function that will send it to a printer.

Comment: Whenever the fullname length changes, the last number at the end of the string shifts, and I need precise accuracy for the printer, it will be a string with three blocks, their value constantly changes but their starting positions are constant within the string. The user cannot change the font. I used the textbox example question to simplify the question, apparently I didn’t, I may need to change the question after all.

Comment: // This is what am trying to accomplish if I were to use Graphics DrawString
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(656, 5);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                Font font = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
                g.Clear(Color.White);
                g.DrawString(first_number, font, Brushes.Black, 10, 1;
                g.DrawString(full_name, font, Brushes.Black, 150, 1);
                g.DrawString(second_number, font, Brushes.Black, 550, 1);
            }

Comment: Could you please update the question, since we now know what is the **real** question - which has nothing to do with a TextBox - possibly explaining what problem you have with the standard way of printing a string of text. Is it the length of the string? You don't know how to measure it? You need to handle strings that don't fit in their reserved space? (...)?

Comment: So, you're trying to print a string using a 14 Points Font (~22 pixels) in a Bitmap which is 5 pixels in height, starting from position Y = 1, so, 4 pixels. Also, you're not providing any sample of the strings you want to print.

Comment: The hard part is trying to figure out your requirements.  I can see using a RichTextBox for this, manipulating the SelectionProtected range, or a DataGridView where the rows and columns allow only 1 character and the important cells are marked read-only.  A lot depends on "your rules".  I'm reading your (15,1) coordinates as the 15th character in the first line.  Maybe I'm way off.  The end result would just translate that data into a string for printing.

Comment: Thank you Jimi, But I do not want to use bitmap, Below is what I want in //pseudo code
String first_number = “123456”;
String fullname = “This text changes all the time”;
String second_number = “654321”;
// Specifying the resulting_string length
String resulting_string;
 resulting_string = length is 600 pixels;
// Finally we build the string by appending the three variables above.
resulting_string = first_number(start appending position = 15 pixels of out of 600) +  fullname(appending position starts= 112 pixels) +  second_number(appending position starts= 480 pixels);

Comment: Why are the pixels so important?

Comment: LarsTech, Please check my comment for jimi, and see the pseudo code, that is what am trying to achieve before passing the final string to the API function for printing, its not a standard printer. and coordinates (15, 1) doesn't mean the 15th characters at the first line it means position 15 in pixels at the width of the string much like stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

Comment: LarsTech; pixels are not important per se, any method that will produce a string with the variables appended at the exact starting positions will be fine.  
Final_string= “       123456             The text that changes                                           654321”;

Whenever we change the variables they should start at the exact same position.

Comment: Then why not use a Label.Text = "123456", TextBox.Text = "text that changes", Label.Text = "654321".  Then "draw" your three components in the exact location you want.

Comment: LarsTech, by draw you mean DrawString method? As far as I know you cannot copy the drawn string if you use DrawString! Am I right? can you help with some code please?

Comment: If you are printing to a printer, why are you printing to a bitmap?  You can just use the PrintDocument class and print to your specific locations.

Comment: LarsTech, Am not printing to a bitmap, the above code with the bitmap accompanying my question is to show what am trying to accomplish, How can I do that using regular string manipulation rather than using bitmap?! and I can not use PrintDocument class because its NOT a generic printer, I can only communicate with the printer using the manufacturer API software, the API only allows me to pass a regular string, that is why am trying to format the string before passing it.

Comment: The reason you have a comment trail here a mile long is because of your XY problem.  You ask for help on one thing, but you really need help on something else.  If all you can pass is a string to your api, then what does it matter what the pixel locations are all about?  These are the details your question should have included.